# How can I upload a .ipynb file to a Notebook Cloud instance?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

The iPython Notebook facilities at https://notebookcloud.appspot.com/ allow you to download the .ipynb file of an iPython notebook. But I can't find a way to upload it into another instance.

Comment: You should be able to drag and drop the file onto the dashboard (the page with the list of notebooks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credit to Thomas K.

You should be able to drag and drop the file onto the dashboard (the page with the list of notebooks) – Thomas K

---

### Update: after one user commented unable to drag-drop:

on the ipython-notebook dashboard page, see the line: "To import a notebook, drag the file onto the listing below or click here." Clicking the 'here' link will bring a dialog box to upload a notebook file.

Comment: on the ipython-notebook dashboard page, see the line: "To import a notebook, drag the file onto the listing below or click here." Clicking the 'here' link will bring a dialog box to upload a notebook file.